# Speeding up SHA256 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've written the following code for computing sha256 in Haskell.  I find the code elegant, but under GHC, it spends an awful lot of time in shaStep and, if I read the profiling data right, a huge amount of time doing memory allocations.  Given that it should be possible to compute sha256 with essentially no memory allocation, I'm looking for tips on how to find out what is doing the allocations, and squashing it.

My code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -funbox-strict-fields #-}
module SHA256 (sha256, sha256Ascii, Hash8) where

import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
import Control.Monad (ap)

ch x y z = (x .&. y) `xor` (complement x .&. z)
maj x y z = (x .&. y) `xor` (x .&. z) `xor` (y .&. z)

bigSigma0 x = rotateR x 2 `xor` rotateR x 13 `xor` rotateR x 22
bigSigma1 x = rotateR x 6 `xor` rotateR x 11 `xor` rotateR x 25
smallSigma0 x = rotateR x 7 `xor` rotateR x 18 `xor` shiftR x 3
smallSigma1 x = rotateR x 17 `xor` rotateR x 19 `xor` shiftR x 10
ks = [0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5
     ,0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174
     ,0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da
     ,0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967
     ,0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85
     ,0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070
     ,0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3
     ,0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2]

blockSize = 16

padding :: Int -> [Word8] -> [[Word32]]
padding blockSize x = unfoldr block $ paddingHelper x 0 (0::Int) (0::Integer)
 where
  block [] = Nothing
  block x = Just $ splitAt blockSize x
  paddingHelper x o on n | on == (bitSize o) = o:paddingHelper x 0 0 n
  paddingHelper (x:xs) o on n | on < (bitSize o) =
    paddingHelper xs ((shiftL o bs) .|. (fromIntegral x)) (on+bs) $! (n+fromIntegral bs)
   where
    bs = bitSize x
  paddingHelper [] o on n = (shiftL (shiftL o 1 .|. 1) (bso-on-1)):
                                (zeros ((-(fromIntegral n-on+3*bso)) `mod` (blockSize*bso)))
                                [fromIntegral (shiftR n bso), fromIntegral n]
       where
        bso = bitSize o
        zeros 0 = id
        zeros n | 0 < n = let z=0 in (z:) . (zeros (n-bitSize z))

data Hash8 = Hash8 {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                   {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

shaStep :: Hash8 -> [Word32] -> Hash8
shaStep h m = foldl' (flip id) h (zipWith mkStep3 ks ws) `plus` h
 where
  ws = m++zipWith4 smallSigma (drop (blockSize-2) ws) (drop (blockSize-7) ws)
                              (drop (blockSize-15) ws) (drop (blockSize-16) ws)
   where
    smallSigma a b c d = smallSigma1 a + b + smallSigma0 c + d
  mkStep3 k w (Hash8 a b c d e f g h) = Hash8 (t1+t2) a b c (d+t1) e f g
   where
    t1 = h + bigSigma1 e + ch e f g + k + w
    t2 = bigSigma0 a + maj a b c
  (Hash8 x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7) `plus` (Hash8 y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7) =
    Hash8 (x0+y0) (x1+y1) (x2+y2) (x3+y3) (x4+y4) (x5+y5) (x6+y6) (x7+y7)

sha :: Hash8 -> [Word8] -> Hash8
sha h0 x = foldl' shaStep h0 $ padding blockSize x

sha256 :: [Word8] -> Hash8
sha256 = sha $
  Hash8 0x6a09e667 0xbb67ae85 0x3c6ef372 0xa54ff53a 0x510e527f 0x9b05688c 0x1f83d9ab 0x5be0cd19

sha256Ascii :: String -> Hash8
sha256Ascii = sha256 . map (fromIntegral . fromEnum)
```

Edit: I just noticed that adding specialized type signatures to `ch`, `maj`, and the big and small sigmas has a huge effect on my profiling results (while not affecting the unprofiled program at all).  Thus it would appear that my program isn't spending nearly as much time in `shaStep` as I was originally lead to believe.

Comment: Every time "ws" does "m++zipWith4..." you end up re-allocating the entire list. Can you start from the other end and use foldr instead?

Comment: Don't use lists, they allocate a lot, and require indirections to perform word-sized operations. Vectors would make more sense.

Comment: @Tim Maybe I can somehow fuse the foldl', zipwith3 mkStep3, and the ws by hand?  The list here is really just a fancy way of writing a for loop.  I had presumed GHC would deforest my list away.

Comment: @Russell O'Connor: I wish I could help but I don't have the skill. I think Don Stewart's suggestion is worth pursuing though.

Comment: You really have no hope of decent performance with `[Word8]`, you must move to something packed, like a bytestring or an unboxed vector or array representation.

Comment: BTW, I think some comments are missing the mark.  It is `shaStep` that is where all the time is spend, and there are no occurances of `[Word8]` in `shaStep`.  The only reason I included the other code is so that people could have the entire module to play around with if they wanted to.

Comment: @Russell I think you're missing the mark.  The current implementation might spend the majority of time in shaStep, but no implementation that uses `[Word32]` as the input will compete with C or ASM based SHA implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the comments I have received so far (thanks everyone!), here is a somewhat improved version of `shaStep`:

```
data Buffer = Buffer {-# UNPACK #-} !Hash8
                     {-# UNPACK #-} !Hash8

shaStep :: Hash8 -> Buffer -> Hash8
shaStep h m = go ks m h `plus` h
 where
  go [] _ h  = h
  go (k:ks) (Buffer (Hash8 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7) (Hash8 a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af)) h =
    go ks (Buffer (Hash8 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8) (Hash8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af ag)) h'
   where
    h' = mkStep3 k a0 h
    ag = smallSigma ae a9 a1 a0 
    smallSigma a b c d = smallSigma1 a + b + smallSigma0 c + d
    mkStep3 k w (Hash8 a b c d e f g h) = Hash8 (t1+t2) a b c (d+t1) e f g
     where
      t1 = h + bigSigma1 e + ch e f g + k + w
      t2 = bigSigma0 a + maj a b c
  (Hash8 x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7) `plus` (Hash8 y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7) =
    Hash8 (x0+y0) (x1+y1) (x2+y2) (x3+y3) (x4+y4) (x5+y5) (x6+y6) (x7+y7)
```

It's not quite as nice as the orginial code since I have to explicitly keep a buffer of 16 `Word32`s by hand, but I guess it is okay. Maybe one can do better still?

The `block` function in `padding` needs to be modified to return a list of `Buffer`s

```
  block [] = Nothing
  block (a0:a1:a2:a3:a4:a5:a6:a7:a8:a9:aa:ab:ac:ad:ae:af:as) = 
    Just (Buffer (Hash8 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7) (Hash8 a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af), as)
```